# How to get position of sprite with a particular tag in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, tags, position, sprite

I'm new to XCode and Obj-C so excuse me if I am missing something obvious here.

I have a project in which I create sprites by calling this addTree function:

```
CCSprite *_tree = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tree.png"];
[self addChild:_tree z:-1 tag:i];

if (i == 0) {
    _tree.position = ccp(100, 100);
}
else if (i > 0) {
    _tree.position = ccp([tree with tag i-1]+20, 100);
}
```

So I call this function using an update method:

```
- (void)adding:(ccTime)dt{
    [self addTree];
    i++;
}
```

This way, each tree spawned will have a tag number one greater than the last.
The first tree spawns at 100,100.

How do I get the subsequent trees to be positioned at the x position of the tree before it (i-1) plus 20?  And is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CCSprite *tree = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i - 1 + 20]; // or any integer
CGPoint position = tree.position;
```

I hope i got you right. Note that `getChildByTag` returns `nil` if there's no child with such a tag